# Graph in Graph editor too small - Animation tab

Tags: animation, keyframes, graph-editor

I'm currently learning blender with the donut tutorial from blender guru. In Part 4, Level 4, he's switching from the "Layout" tab to the "Animation" tab at 5:27. [Here's a link to the video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLIimJxTyNw). Now, my problem is: the graph editor is tiny. I can see the different vertices, but the graphs are very close to each other. I've looked in the settings tab, looked after a solution on the internet (especially here), but I can't find anything that solves the problem. [image: Here's a picture. You can see: I do have six objects, but they are very close to each other so the graph seems like it's only one line]

Thanks for your help! I am looking forward to your answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>-<kbd>SPACE</kbd> when hovering over the editor -> full screen

Comment: Thank you, it's now working!

Comment: you are welcome. just hit the same shortcut again, to go back to normal size. By the way -> you can do this with any panel.

Answer (score 4):

For expanding the editor window aka timeline editor, just select the edge of the timeline window and move it up/down to your liking.

To enlarge timeline graphs, simply zoom in/out with the mouse wheel while hovering over the timeline editor window.

You can also hold <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and use <kbd>[image: MMB] MMB</kbd> (Middle Mouse Button) to scale along a desired axis.

Answer (score 0):

I found another solution myself now (Blender guru says that in his video, but a bit later): Just press pos1, also known as "Home Key". It will center at the existing keyframes.